# Multiple string functions on string?

Tags: php

If you have many string functions on one string, what is the best thing to do?

```
$string = strip_tags(utf8_decode(html_entity_decode(str_replace(["\r\n\r\n", "<br />", "<br>", "</p>"], "\r\n", $string), ENT_QUOTES)));
```

This is a code snippit from my script, and I think it looks horrible, but I need all of these functions on this string...
I use this only once, so putting it in a function is overkill imo.

If you have any suggestions, please let me know :)

P.s. still a beginner at PHP...

Comment: I think you're fine, any other solution will be a repetition, except you want something totally different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use proper indentation to enhance the readability of the code:

```
$string = strip_tags(
    utf8_decode(
        html_entity_decode(
            str_replace(
                [
                    "\r\n\r\n", 
                    '<br />', 
                    '<br>', 
                    '</p>'
                ], 
                "\r\n", 
                $string
            ), 
            ENT_QUOTES
        )
    )
);
```

But regardless of that I definitely would recommend to move such code into a separate function! That allows you to chose a name that describes what it actually does, so that you can keep the internal details of that logic out of the code where you apply it.

Comment: Thank you, I used your code in a function, and it indeed looks better, and most certainly more readable!

Comment: You are welcome. To keep things a bit more compact one could also keep the four patterns to be `str_replace()`ed in a single row, so `["\r\n\r\n", '<br />', '<br>', '</p>']`.

Answer (score 1):

> I use this only once, so putting it in a function is overkill imo.

I totally do not second that. The intent of your code is anything but obvious and you would make your code way more readable - and hence maintainable - if you put the line in a method

```
function remove_all_tags($string)
{
    return strip_tags(utf8_decode(html_entity_decode(str_replace(["\r\n\r\n", "<br />", "<br>", "</p>"], "\r\n", $string), ENT_QUOTES)));
}
```

I'd furthermore suggest to separate the calls to make the intent clearer

```
function remove_all_tags($string)
{
    $stringWithUnifiedNewline = str_replace(["\r\n\r\n", "<br />", "<br>", "</p>"], "\r\n", $string);
    $htmlDecodedString = html_entity_decode($stringWithUnifiedNewline, ENT_QUOTES)
    $utf8DecodedString = utf8_decode($htmlDecodedString);
    return strip_tags($utf8DecodedString);
}
```

Now compare your original code

```
$string = strip_tags(utf8_decode(html_entity_decode(str_replace(["\r\n\r\n", "<br />", "<br>", "</p>"], "\r\n", $string), ENT_QUOTES)));
```

to

```
$string = remove_all_tags($string);
```

Your intent is clearer, the code cleaner and everyone's happy.

Comment: Thanks, I did not end up using your version since the answer I accepted is a bit more readable, even though it uses much more space.
Your code is very clear in what it does though, +1 for that ^^